# Parsing a user's SAML attributes via Foundry's Multipass or Control Panel

Tags: regex, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

I want to add more metadata to last names in Palantir Foundry's Multipass for our users (for instance, to display Anna Smith, USA (Contractor)). My SAML integration has attributes `employee_type: CONTRACTOR` and `certificate_cn name=SMITH.ANNA,OU=USA`.

How do I parse out further attributes from the certificate CN & format them as part of the last name? Do either Control Panel or Multipass configuration let me use regular expressions to extract on the SAML attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipass does not currently support parsing attributes using regular expressions.